# Port and protocol used for a Remote Desktop Connection (on Win 7)

Tags: windows-7, port, protocols, remote-desktop

How to know which port and which protocol is being used when a Remote Desktop Connection is established on Win7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a proprietary Windows protocol ("Remote Desktop Protocol"), using TCP port 3389, and UDP port 3389.  Wikipedia entry [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol).